# Change first two letters in Excel columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 17 sheets in Excel where I have to change the first two letters of the active cells in the column WU everyday. I have tried to do this using the following code

```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Becasue there are only 26*26 (676 Days) Possible prefixes at some point we have to start at AA again.
Dim TDate As Date
Dim SDate As Date
Dim DaysSpaned As Integer
Dim FirstLet As Integer
Dim SecondLet As Integer
Dim Let1 As String
Dim Let2 As String
Dim ReplaceString As String
Dim String_2_Replace As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

SDate = "10/5/2016" 'SET THE SATRTING DATE 10/3/2016
TDate = Format(Date, "Short Date") 'Convert the date format to MM / DD / YYYY

If TDate - SDate >= 7 Then  'We are counting WORKDAYS NOT TOTAL DAYS SO WE MUST REMOVE SAT AND SUN FROM THE CALC _ IF WE WANT TO COUNT WEEKENDS CHANGE THE
                            '"w" below to "d" and delete the lines of code with '*DEL after them and the If Statement on the line above this one
DaysSpaned = DateDiff("w", SDate, TDate) 'COUNTS WEEKS
DaysSpaned = DaysSpaned * 5 ' this line changes weeks to work days '*DEL
Else '*DEL
DaysSpaned = TDate - SDate '*Del
End If                      '*Del

'RESET THE COUNTER BACK TO AA FROM ZZ
Do Until DaysSpaned < 678
DaysSpaned = DaysSpaned - 676
Loop
'Day 1 = AA - Day 26 = BA so the first letter changes everyday

FirstLet = DaysSpaned / 2 - 1
SecondLet = DaysSpaned Mod 2

Select Case FirstLet
Case Is = 0
    Let1 = "A"
Case Is = 1
    Let1 = "B"
Case Is = 2
    Let1 = "C"
Case Is = 3
    Let1 = "D"
Case Is = 4
    Let1 = "E"
Case Is = 5
    Let1 = "F"
Case Is = 6
    Let1 = "G"
Case Is = 7
    Let1 = "H"
Case Is = 8
    Let1 = "I"
Case Is = 9
    Let1 = "J"
Case Is = 10
    Let1 = "K"
Case Is = 11
    Let1 = "L"
Case Is = 12
    Let1 = "M"
Case Is = 13
    Let1 = "N"
Case Is = 14
    Let1 = "O"
Case Is = 15
    Let1 = "P"
Case Is = 16
    Let1 = "D"
Case Is = 17
    Let1 = "R"
Case Is = 18
    Let1 = "S"
Case Is = 19
    Let1 = "T"
Case Is = 20
    Let1 = "U"

Case Is = 21
    Let1 = "V"
Case Is = 22
    Let1 = "W"
Case Is = 23
    Let1 = "X"
Case Is = 24
    Let1 = "Y"
Case Is = 25
    Let1 = "Z"

End Select

Select Case SecondLet
Case Is = 0
    Let2 = "A"
Case Is = 1
    Let2 = "B"
Case Is = 2
    Let2 = "C"
Case Is = 3
    Let2 = "D"
Case Is = 4
    Let2 = "E"
Case Is = 5
    Let2 = "F"
Case Is = 6
    Let2 = "G"
Case Is = 7
    Let2 = "H"
Case Is = 8
    Let2 = "I"
Case Is = 9
    Let2 = "J"
Case Is = 10
    Let2 = "K"
Case Is = 11
    Let2 = "L"
Case Is = 12
    Let2 = "M"
Case Is = 13
    Let2 = "N"
Case Is = 14
    Let2 = "O"
Case Is = 15
    Let2 = "P"
Case Is = 16
    Let2 = "Q"
Case Is = 17
    Let2 = "R"
Case Is = 18
    Let2 = "S"
Case Is = 19
    Let2 = "T"
Case Is = 20
    Let2 = "U"

Case Is = 21
    Let2 = "V"
Case Is = 22
    Let2 = "W"
Case Is = 23
    Let2 = "X"
Case Is = 24
    Let2 = "Y"
Case Is = 25
    Let2 = "Z"

End Select


ReplaceString = Let1 & Let2  ' COMBINE THE LETTERS
String_2_Replace = Left(Range("WU2").Value, 2)  'UPDATE THE STRING TO REPLACE AS IT WAS CHANGED FROM li

         'Actually replace the String
         Worksheets("ADMIN_ARB11").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

          Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_ARB13").Activate
         Columns("WU:WU").Select

        Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FVB1").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

          Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FVB1E").Activate
         Columns("WU:WU").Select

          Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FVB4").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

          Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
          ReplaceFormat:=False

          Worksheets("ADMIN_FVB4E").Activate
          Columns("WU:WU").Select

         Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

                  Worksheets("ADMIN_FV10").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

        Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FV1").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

          Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FV16").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

          Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString,  LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FV57").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

             Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace,     Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FV58").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

        Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FV60").Activate
Columns("WU:WU").Select

        Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString,  LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_AR14").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

         Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_SR12").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

        Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString,  LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FVE0").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

        Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString,   LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FV1E").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

         Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString,   LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        Worksheets("ADMIN_FVE6").Activate
        Columns("WU:WU").Select

          Selection.Replace What:=String_2_Replace, Replacement:=ReplaceString,     LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     End Sub
```

But the above code truncates the values in the cells of WU column. Where am I going wrong in the code? or is there any other simpler solution with a formula or VBA code?

Comment: An example of the trunction? You don't specify a sheet in the String_2_Replace line which may or may not matter.

Comment: DF8m00001 was the value in the WU1. it changed to A8m00001 and when I run it again it changed to m00001 and next it changed to 1. Although I was changing the SDate with values of today tomorrow and day after tomorrow

Comment: Looks like ReplaceString is empty.

Comment: Yes I think so too. but where am i going wrong with it?

Comment: have you stepped through the code to check the values of Firstlet and secondlet?

Answer (score 0):

The variables String_2_Replace and ReplaceString are strings. I think their values have to be between "" in the Selection.Replace statements.

Comment: The values are not truncated also they are not changed

Comment: OK. And in you example, "DF" you want it changed to what letters?

Comment: You replace in the column WU but you read String_2_Replace from WU2. May be you have to change WU2 to WU.

Comment: If I give in the succeeding days it must be DG, DH

Comment: My cell values start from WU2

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it can help you :

I found Lettre2NumCol in the internet. I use ColAddress in my programs most of times.

the value in A1 is DF8m00001, in Sheet1.

```
Sub test()
    Dim var1 As String, var2 As Integer, var3 As String

    var1 = Left(Range("A1"), 2)
     var2 = Lettre2NumCol(var1) + 1
     var3 = ColAddress(var2)

     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Columns("A:A").Select

          Selection.Replace What:=var1, Replacement:=var3, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub


Function ColAddress(col As Integer) As String
    Dim vArray
    If col <> 0 Then
        vArray = Split(Cells(1, col).Address(True, False), "$")
        Else
            MsgBox "Problem"
            End
    End If
    ColAddress = vArray(0)
End Function

Public Function Lettre2NumCol(ByVal Chaine As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long, ValeurCh As Long, v As Long
    Const ChaineAlpha As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    For i = 1 To Len(Chaine)
    ValeurCh = InStr(1, ChaineAlpha, Mid(UCase(Chaine), i, 1))
    v = v * 26 + ValeurCh
    Next
    Lettre2NumCol = v
End Function
```